# Stripe input fields width is very less

Tags: css, woocommerce

I have installed Stripe on my WooCommerce Store. Upon testing I found that that Stripe checkout form input fields have very less width and they are coming from Strip Iframe.

I have tried adjusting it using CSS, but the width CSS is inline and coming from Stripe site.

Please recommend how can I fix it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rL5Ay.jpg "Screenshot"

Thanks

Comment: How did you install? Is it a plugin? If so, css could be controlled by the plugin. You won't be able to override styles within iframe if they come from other site.

Comment: yes, It is a plugin by WooCommerce called WooCommerce Stripe Gateway

Answer (score 2):

You are missing some styling elements in your woocomerce theme code, add this to your theme child or your custom theme css file

```
.stripe-card-group, div#stripe-cvc-element, div#stripe-exp-element {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Comment: This code snippet worked for me Brad _ though I also added `!important;`